# Limpar y quitar decimales en R funcion cut

Tags: r

se esta usando la data titanic y me tiene que dar este resultado

```
##   Survived Pclass   Age     Sex      agecat
##          0      3    22    male    15 to 50
##          1      1    38  female    15 to 50
##          1      3    26  female    15 to 50
##          1      1    35  female    15 to 50
##          0      3    35    male    15 to 50
##          0      1    54    male     Over 50
```

y he intentado para que me de el mismo dataframe pero el código mas cercano que ha salido es este

```
titanic_3 <- titanic %>% 
  select(Survived, Pclass, Age, Sex) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Age)) %>%
  mutate(agecat = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 14.9, 50, 150), 
                      include.lowest = TRUE,
                      labels = c("Under 15", "15 to 50", "Over 50")))
```

y no se como quitarle los decimales a la variable Age del resultado final, ademas se esta usando el paquete tidyverse

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos criterios a la hora de decidir que hacer con la parte decimal: (1) la descartamos (2) la redondeamos:

```
titanic %>% 
  mutate(Age1 = as.integer(Age),       # Descartamos los decimales
         Age2 = as.integer(round(Age)) # Redondeamos
  ) %>% 
  select(Age, Age1, Age2) %>% 
  filter(Age1 != Age2)

     Age Age1 Age2
1   0.83    0    1
2  55.50   55   56
3  45.50   45   46
4  23.50   23   24
5   0.92    0    1
6  45.50   45   46
7   0.75    0    1
8   0.75    0    1
9   0.67    0    1
10  0.83    0    1
11 11.50   11   12
12  0.92    0    1
13  0.75    0    1
14  0.83    0    1
```

El código anterior transforma la columna `Age` en una columna `integer`, si quieres mantener el mismo tipo de datos, el `round()` funcionaría bien, pero para truncar podrías usar `floor(Age)`.

Te sugiero, luego de eliminar los decimales, un `cut` como el siguiente:

```
Age <- c(14, 15, 49, 50, 51)
cut(Age, 
    breaks = c(-Inf, 14, 50, Inf), 
    labels = c("Under 15", "15 to 50", "Over 50"))
```